# How to set azure alerts with Terraform

Tags: azure, alert, terraform

Is there anyway to create alert using some sort of azure api on a given resource using Terraform, on the creation of the cluster

Comment: Which API do you mean? run the API in the Terraform template?

Comment: @CharlesXu. The objective would be, at the time of running the Terraform to set up the cluster, i would also like to set up the azure alerts (log query alerts).
So I can deploy the Terraform template and get everything up and running. Otherwise i will have to manually set up the alerts every time i create a new cluster.

Comment: What do you want to create and monitor? The cluster? What cluster?

Comment: The answer is this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal
Json templates that allow the creation of alerts and action groups.
And you can just put them in the terraform template

Comment: Do you solve the problem? If you have solved it. You can add the answer for others who find it.

Answer (score 2):

you can get a json template example here, for alerts and action groups creation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal

terraform 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html